# How to shift the part of the list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function

```
def rotate(a, n, k):
   pass
```

I need to get list `a`, select the first `n` items and shift them `k` places to right or left (positive to right and negative to left).

For Example:

```
rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, 2) 
    => [4,5,1,2,3,6,7,8,9]
```

I try

```
def rotate(a, n, k):
    movable = a[:n]
    const = a[:n]

    for item in movable:
        const[k] = item
```

But it doesn't work right.

Comment: Check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_slice.asp

Comment: "it doesn't work right" is not a question. What is wrong with your code? Being able to identify how the outcome of your code differs from what you expect is important if you are to be a successful programmer. What does your code give? What did you expect it to give? Did you do any [research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) or [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use list concatenation:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n=3
k=2
rotated = l[:n] + l[n:n+k] + l[n+k:]
```

results in `rotated=[4,5,1,2,3,6,7,8,9]`